# Grease Pencil: is it possible to have a vector-app like rendering?

Tags: rendering, workflow, grease-pencil, vector

I love Grease Pencil but I can’t find a way to draw with a really « vector » look; it always looks like a pencil drawing,with jiggly lines.  Which is nice most of the time; but here I want to have an « Illustrator » look : clean drawings, with an equal thickness everywhere.

Is that possible and how ?

Thanks!

Comment: I don’t know what you’re talking about, but if I do it with a mouse I always end up with lines of the same thickness, and even on a tablet I can turn the pressure setting off. Can you add screenshots to demonstrate what you’re looking for?

Comment: what @TheLabCat said + in Stroke menu, enabling stabilize stroke could help